# Structure formatting issue, cannot convert

Tags: c++, arrays, 2d, structure

I keep getting the same error while compiling.  Brief background, this program takes two integers from the user (say m, n), creates a 2D array (with m rows and n columns), then computes and prints the multiplication and division tables for those values.

I do apologize as I am running a little low on sleep (and coffee).  Please be as kind as you can as it has been over two years since I last wrote code.

The error I am receiving is as follows:

```
test1.cpp: In function ‘void createTable(int, int)’:
test1.cpp:69: error: cannot convert ‘mult_div_values (*)[(((long unsigned int)(((long int)n) + -0x00000000000000001)) + 1)]’ to ‘mult_div_values**’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void multArray(mult_div_values**, int, int)’
test1.cpp:70: error: cannot convert ‘mult_div_values (*)[(((long unsigned int)(((long int)n) + -0x00000000000000001)) + 1)]’ to ‘mult_div_values**’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void divArray(mult_div_values**, int, int)’
```

Clearly, the issue lies in this function, but I can't figure out what the issue is, if someone could give me a hint as to what I am looking for, I would greatly appreciate it.

```c++
void createTable(int m, int n)
{
    struct mult_div_values table [m][n]; //Initialize table array

    multArray(table, m, n);
    divArray(table, m, n);

    return;
}
```

The entire code (I do apologize if my code makes you pros cringe):

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h> //atoi function
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

//Declare structure for multiplication and division values
struct mult_div_values {
    int mult;
    float div;
};

//Prototype functions
void multArray(mult_div_values** table, int m, int n);
void divArray(mult_div_values** table, int m, int n);
void createTable(int m, int n);
void checkValues(char* argv[]);
void printMult(mult_div_values** table, int m, int n);
void printdiv(mult_div_values** table, int m, int n);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{    
    checkValues(argv); //Passes argument values to check for validity.

    return 0;
}

/*********************************************************************
 ** Parameters: Takes in the 1st and 2nd character arguments from the command line.
 ** Description: Checks that arguments are in fact numbers.  Converts value from character to integer.
 ** Return value: Converted integer values.
 *********************************************************************/
void checkValues(char* argv[])
{   
    //Convert char to int
    int m = atoi(argv[1]);
    int n = atoi(argv[2]);

    //Check that in is 
    if ((m < 1) || (n < 1))
    {
       cout << "Error!" << endl;
    }
    cout << m << n << endl;

    createTable(m, n);

}

/*********************************************************************
 ** Parameters: Takes in column and row values.
 ** Description: Initializes table array.
 *********************************************************************/
void createTable(int m, int n)
{
    struct mult_div_values table [m][n]; //Initialize table array

    multArray(table, m, n);
    divArray(table, m, n);

    return;
}

/*********************************************************************
 ** Parameters: Takes in table array and number of columns/rows.
 ** Description: Computes multiplication values.
 *********************************************************************/
void multArray(mult_div_values** table, int m, int n)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= m; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
        {
            table[i - 1][j - 1].mult = i*j;
        }
    }

    return;
}

/*********************************************************************
 ** Parameters: Takes in table array and number of columns/rows.
 ** Description: Computes division values.
 *********************************************************************/
void divArray(mult_div_values** table, int m, int n)
{

    for (int i = 1; i <= m; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
        {
            table[i - 1][j - 1].div = i/j;
        }
    }

    return;
}

/*********************************************************************
 ** Parameters: Takes in multiplication values and number of columns/rows.
 ** Description: Builds multiplication table and prints.
 *********************************************************************/
void printMult(mult_div_values** table, int m, int n)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            cout << table[i][j].mult << "\t";
        }

        cout << endl;
    }

    return;
}

/*********************************************************************
 ** Parameters: Takes in division values and number of columns/rows.
 ** Description: Builds division table and prints.
 *********************************************************************/
void printdiv(mult_div_values** table, int m, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            cout << table[i][j].div << "\t";
        }

        cout << endl;
    }

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A 2-dimensional array (a matrix) is not an array of pointers (your formal arguments).

Also note that this code,

```
struct mult_div_values table [m][n];
```

is not valid C++, because `m` and `n` are not compile time constants. It's accepted by g++ (and presumably by clang) as a *language extension*. You'd better turn that off by specifying `-std=c++11` and `-pedantic`.

Also note that it's C style, not C++.

In C++ you don't need to repeat the `struct` keyword there.

A good way to do this variable size matrix in C++ is to use a `std::vector`, either with each item a `std::vector`, or with 2D indexing mapped to 1D indexing. You can wrap that up in a class easily.

Comment: Again, forgive my ignorance, but are you referring to the pointer here: mult_div_values**

Comment: -1 "an array of pointers (your formal arguments)" - pointer to pointer is not array of pointers

Comment: @kotlomoy: in the context of a formal argument intended to take a logical matrix, a pointer to a pointer represents a pointer to first item of an array of pointers. although it's not the quality it used to have, there is a list of C++ learner's books here on SO. it's worth checking out.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: "in the context of a formal argument intended to take a logical matrix, a pointer to a pointer represents a pointer to first item of an array of pointers" - what? You don't need array of pointers to pass matrix to function.

Comment: @kotlomoy: there are two main basic representations of matrices. one is like `int a[7][3];`, where the items are stored contiguously in memory, and which is called *multidimensional array*. this is the representation used in the OP's calling code. the other is like `int* a[7]; for( int i = 0; i < 7; ++i) { a[i] = new int[3](); }`, i.e. an array of pointers to arrays, which is called a *jagged array*. this is the representation assumed by the OP's formal function arguments. the two formats allow the same indexing notation, but they're incompatible memory layouts.

Comment: the main advantage of the jagged array representation is that it supports writing general code that can work with dynamic (established at run time) array sizes for all dimensions. with the multidimensional general non-templated code can only deal with variation in the outermost dimension. if it wants support from the C or C++ type system, that is.

Comment: mostly this should be explained in any good introductory book, which is why i pointed in that direction. ;-)

Comment: We haven't covered classes yet and at this point, I had a hard enough time figuring out "what I should have remembered".  Anyhow, I solved the issue, thank you for the information!

Answer (score 0):

```
void createTable(int m, int n)
{
//Initialize table array
mult_div_values** table = new mult_div_values*[n]; 
for(int i = 0; i < n ; i++){

    table[i] = new mult_div_values[m];

}

//Call mult and div funtions
multArray(table, m, n);
divArray(table, m, n);

delete [] table; //Clear allocation

return;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, certain values cause a segmentation fault, but that is a story for a different day.